# Globalize tags for certain controller names in OpenAPI

Tags: openapi, openapi-generator

i am having issues with  OpenAPI , so here i am asking for help.

My problem is that i am having a .yml file where my routes are imported [and it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJ5bv.png)

as you can see the persons such as assets are in default what i want to do is to give them tags to be separated from each other so [it looks like this for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qxv5Y.png)

So what i did is when there is for example a GET method then i give a tag to it like that:

```
  paths:
  "/persons/{person_id}/":
    get:
      tags:
        - Person
      summary: persons#index":
```

i defined a global tags variable  at the top like this:

```
tags:
  - name: Person
  - name: Asset
```

My problem is that i am having more than 1000 lines of code and i am not able to  write these lines of code   manually under every piece of get method

Is there  a way to kinda make it easier? I am thinking of something like this when you define a tag and you pass everything under that should belong to that tag.

Kinda like this:

```
tags:
  - name: Person
  paths:
     "/persons/{person_id}/load_autocomplete_parent":
      get:
      summary: persons#load_autocomplete_parent
    "/persons/load_autocomplete":
    get:
      summary: persons#load_autocomplete
  "/persons/load_name":
    get:
      summary: persons#load_name
  "/persons/tree":
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not the answer you are looking for, but no, you can't do anything like that.

According to the specification you can use the `tags` field in two place:

- the [OpenAPI Object](https://swagger.io/specification/#openapi-object), the root of your document, where you can have a *a list of tags used by the specification with additional metadata*, that is, the global tags that you mentioned.
- the [Operation Object](https://swagger.io/specification/#operation-object), that *describes a single API operation on a path.* This is what you are already doing in the single endpoints.